# projects.map is not a function for jest-cli

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am writing a react app and testing it with jest. However, whenever I run the `jest` command from the terminal, I keep this error.

```
TypeError: projects.map is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/DavidHu/Desktop/coding/projects/swapnow/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:172:28)
    at next (native)
    at step (/Users/DavidHu/Desktop/coding/projects/swapnow/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:18:30)
    at /Users/DavidHu/Desktop/coding/projects/swapnow/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:34:14
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/DavidHu/Desktop/coding/projects/swapnow/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:15:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as runCLI] (/Users/DavidHu/Desktop/coding/projects/swapnow/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:2 03:17)
    at Object.run (/Users/DavidHu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:42:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/DavidHu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:16:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
```

I went into `node_modules` to look at the line of code that is causing the error, `projects` is a string of the project current path.

Here is my jest configuration in `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ]
  }
```

Has anyone encountered this error and know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know the exact solution here,  but .map is part of the array prototype.

Comment: Can you show your jest configuration? Is this failing for all tests or only one in particular?

Comment: @Nick, I updated the question with the jest configs. This is failing for all tests. Even if I remove all the tests, this error still shows up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem. If you look at your stack trace closely you'll notice that you run two different Jest setups:

Globally installed jest:

```
...(/Users/DavidHu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:16:25)
```

Jest from the project:

```
...(/Users/DavidHu/Desktop/coding/projects/swapnow/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/runCLI.js:172:28)
```

They are probably have different (and incompatible) versions.
If you remove jest from your project (or from global `node_modules`) that should solve the problem.

Comment: Removing Jest from the project should definitely be the last option. Anyone coming into your project, or even yourself 6 months from now will thank you when you know what version of Jest to run/works on your project.

Answer (score 7):

This will happen if you update jest in your project but run it using just `jest` from the command line (not from node_modules).

To fix you'll need to update your global jest:

`npm install -g jest`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I was passing a string to the 'projects' parameter instead of an array.

Wrapping the string 'projectPath' in [] fixed it for me (this is located inside a Gulp task):

```
var jestCLI = require('jest-cli');
...
jestCLI.runCLI({'onlyChanged': true}, [projectPath], callback);
```

Comment: My problem was similar where I passed in dirname instead of [dirname]. Also, I'm on v22 at the moment, so maybe answers above are applicable to previous versions. Reinstalling didn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue with local and project installations of jest-cli. I removed the project installation of jest-cli and got the issue resolved.